# How to ZIP an Excel file using python?

Tags: python, excel

How can I zip a excel file using python ?
I have a excel sheet. I want to change ZIP the excel Sheet Using Python.
So that It can have less network usages when I try to download from mine Site.
Just Another Requirements.

Thanks in Advance.
Please Help

Comment: Check out the [`zipfile`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html?highlight=zipfile#zipfile) module.

Comment: Aren't Excel files zip packages to begin with? What's the point in double zipping?

Comment: @user3085379: freakish is correct. Try opening a random xlsx file in your favourite zip tool, and you'll see it for yourself

Comment: @pnuts I think xls is a zip container as well. At least, I'm able to open the file in 7-zip. Inside the file, it's 3 different files

Comment: But it seems like you can decrease the size of (xlsx) excel files anyway. Check out [this](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/how-to-compress-xlsx-files-to-the-smallest-possible-size/) link.

Comment: Thanks all. this Zip is nor really effective. The Compression ratio is just around 3% of the file.if the file is like 12,187KB the Compressed file is 12,100KB only. Any Other way to do the thing, I want to compress the file.

Answer (score 1):

Python's built in zipfile library can be used to compress any file. Below code should work for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import zipfile

zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile('file_name.zip', 'w')
zip_file.write('/tmp/hello.txt')
zip_file.close()
```

Comment: This Zip is nor really effective. The Compression ratio is just around 3% of the file.if the file is like 12,187KB the Compressed file is 12,100KB only. Any Other way to do the thing, I want to compress the file more.

Comment: Compression ratio depends upon the file type, text files gets compressed very well up to 90% but binary files like images, documents and others will not be that effective. you can try other compression technique like bz2, 7zip variants in which you might get slightly more compression.